# window.load and document.load in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have big problem with

```
   $(window).load(function() {    // this not working in chrome
```

and

```
   $(document).load(function() {   // this not working in firefox
```

if i use the first it will not be fired in chrome

if i use the second it will not be fired in firefox

How to fix that ?

im trying to do the scroll the page like that

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).load(function() {
       $("html, body ").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10);
   });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      // some othe code here which doesnt affect anything just to show that im using document ready here
    });
   </script>
```

If someone wonder , im also changing this `$(window).height()` in the code to `document`

**EDIT**

```
    $(document).load(function() {
        $("html, body , #mydiv1,#mydiv2").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10);
 });
        $(document).ready(function () {
           var $window = $(document),
            $stickyEl = $('#listholder'),
            elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

       $window.scroll(function() {
      $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
          });
     scroll("#mydiv1,#mydiv2");

  });
```

Comment: window & window? You mean document and window?

Comment: @seahorsepip sorry i fixed that .

Comment: @Guedes thanks it fixed your answer :)

Comment: Devil's advocate solution: ``$(window, document)``

Comment: Try also moving the content of `$(window).load` to inside `$(document).ready(`

Comment: @Guedes that's not a solution, what if he wants that code to execute after all the images are loaded?

Comment: `$( window ).load(function() {` will fire if all content is loaded in both chrome and firefox. If you register `$( window ).load(function() {`  after this event was already fired, then it won't be called anymore. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzyhubq5/), it works in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: I think `$('.my-imgs').load(function(){})` works inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: @seahorsepip your answer $(window, document)` wont work either .

Comment: @Guedes solution to move the script in the end of page worked .

Comment: @ScooterDaraf if moving `$(window).load(function() {` to the end the document works for you, then the error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: Did you check your console for errors and warnings? Those errors and warnings aren't decoration :P

Comment: i have no error , just not fireing .

Comment: I will update my whole code which working now

Comment: @seahorsepip edited the working code . i dont know if there was something wrong in my code . I m setting that in the end of page

Comment: You might consider pressing F12 and reading the console to check if anything is going wrong.

Comment: @seahorsepip i know nothing wrong in console ,